# JavaScript: Ancient code starts simple object using 'new' keyword. Why?

Tags: javascript, constructor

I guess I'm still relatively new to JS development, and during some refactoring of ancient JS code (proof: there's still usage of the 'with' statement in there), I've come across the following:

```
var result = new {
    key: 'value'
    // etc...
}
```

Why is the `new` keyword used? Is there a difference between this and the following?

```
var result = {
    key: 'value'
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: `new` keyword is used to cause errors. At least now it will. Dunno is it was supported earlier.

Comment: how does _with_ == ancient  ?  (new is likely a typo here)

Comment: I wouldn't cite the `with` keyword as sign that code is old. While I don't generally recommend using it, there are some frameworks (namely frameworks that use templating such as KendoUI) that make good use of it.

Comment: @dandavis no typos I'm afraid. Asking about the `new` keyword specifically, not `with`.

Comment: @BrianBall I definitely would. Been deprecated for 4 years, and recommended almost universally to not use it due to a security risk. Good use aside, it shouldn't be used at all.

Comment: but what are you asking about that use of _new_ though?  someone didn't understand it once upon a time and misused it, and leter you came across it, what's the big deal?  you haven't stumbled across some secret usage.

Comment: a "security risk" by using _with_? this i gotta see. gotta link?

Comment: @dandavis it makes behavior analysis really hard. Consider `with` used with a reference to an argument to a function. Also, `with` is disallowed in "strict" mode.

Comment: @dandavis haha, [here you go](http://www.2ality.com/2011/06/with-statement.html). "with violates lexical scope, making program analysis (e.g. for security) hard to infeasible." My wording may have been a little extreme, but there is a "security" concern.

Comment: @dandavis well that's exactly what I was wondering. I can't get into the minds of the previous developers, and couldn't think (or find) a reason for it!

Comment: i am aware that ES3CP/ES5.strict don't support it, and of it's potential gotchas, but to say that it's a security risk is simply misleading. how many people use "program analysis" to validate security? i've never seen that done or recommended, ever, except with ports like FBJS. in short, _with_ has enough strikes against it that we need not overstate theoretical reasons not to implement it... besides, its _eval()_ that's the infamous security risk... how about we all just not use _new_ or _with_ ?

Comment: @dandavis rather unfortunate that this turned into a small discussion about something unrelated to my actual question...

Comment: you asked why someone sometime did something useless, but nobody knows why, besides whomever wrote it. The other parts of your question were/are more easily addressed. in short, i don't think there's really a good answer to be had. Sorry if i wasted time drilling to that conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

After wasted time of researching this and waiting to see if anyone had any clue what these previous devs were doing, I've decided to answer it myself.

From a separate Stack question, located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript), this seemed a little relevant:

> It creates a new object. The type of this object, is simply object.

So whether it worked in an old browser or whatever, it *appears* that this snippet was a disjointed way of creating a new `object`. Modern browsers (Chrome) throw syntax errors upon encountering this, so if it ever was valid, it isn't now.

Comment: It's a TypeError, not a syntax error. The difference is that if your code contains a syntax error, none of it will run, whereas a TypeError only happens when the line of code containing the error runs (and maybe it never will).